# Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install, no internet (Ethernet)

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet, ethernet

I installed a fresh Ubuntu beside Windows 10. In Windows, I have Internet access by ethernet. In Ubuntu, I can see a Wired Connection 1, but without internet access.
I am behind a local network.

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Here are the outcomes of some commands:

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgVKD.jpg)

[sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miwuo.jpg)

[sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrrsU.jpg)

[sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5N7I.jpg)

I have tried to set interfaces to:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet auto
```

and then restart the network manager/ reboot, but it didn't work. If fact, as soon as the restart occured, the enp0s31f6 interface was not shown in ifconfig.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Normal internet connection, via USB tethering

Tried sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, still NO internet connection via ETHERNET

EDIT2:

> Output for: sudo dhclient -d enp0s31f6

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/64:00:6a:90:e0:92
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/64:00:6a:90:e0:92
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb123492d)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xb123492d)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

EDIT3:
Below, output of:
    `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-=========================================================
un  dnsmasq                    <none>             <none>             (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base               2.75-1ubuntu0.16.0 amd64              Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
```

EDIT 4:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

connect: Network is unreachable

```
ping www.ebay.com
```

ping: unknown host www.ebay.com
 Also, this is  what I see now in the network section (I use tethering in order to have internet access for now)

[image]

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: You are right, however, I don't have internet access, so I would have to type them.

Comment: What kind of network? Does it use [802.1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) to authenticate clients? This would be common in many corporate settings

Comment: No @vidarlo, no such authentication.

Comment: what is the output of `dhclient -d enp0s31f6`? Do you know anything more about the network? Your NIC should be fairly well supported.

Comment: @vidarlo, I updated the question with the output. I know that my workstation with Windows 10, has ethernet access with DHCP with no issues.

Comment: Is it your home network?

Comment: @LaraLarsen have you tried mii-tool. Use the -w option to see if the hardware is even detecting the cable or not?

Comment: mii-tool outputs: SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not permitted ... No MII interfaces found

Comment: The Ethernet is recognized as Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V in the toolbar network section.

Comment: Set `/etc/network/interfaces` back to default. Check the DHCP settings in your router. Make sure they have a large enough range to cover all of your DHCP requests from clients. POWER CYCLE the router by UNPLUGGING it, wait 30 seconds, replug, retest.

Comment: @heynnema, I reverted every change that did not solve the issue. DHCP settings should be fine, another pc with Windows has internet access and the same pc with Windows has access as well.

Comment: Did you power cycle the router as per my suggestion?

Comment: yes @heynnema, did not work.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`. In /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf did you manually add dns=dnsmasq?

Comment: @heynnema, I just did, thank you for your time.

Comment: @LaraLarsen Thanks for the dpkg info. My question about /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and dns=dnsmasq was... how did that get there? Did you place it there, or was it put there automatically? Edit your question and show me `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping www.ebay.com`. Thanks.

Comment: It was there already @heynnema. I tried to comment it but no change.

Comment: @LaraLarsen Try two things. Do you have a wireless router? If so, are you able to make a wireless connection? Second, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the network works that way. Report back.

Comment: I do have a wireless router, but no wireless adapter in my desktop. However, few months ago, I tried to setup another workstation as dual-boot with Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04. I had the same issue with ethernet, although in win10 it works fine. At that time, I used a wireless adapter to connect to the network. I never managed to resolve the Ethernet issue. 2/ I tried to boot to a ubuntu live USB and I have the same error (and the same outputs in the commands as I mentioned before.) It makes sense as it is the same I used for the setup. Maybe I should try a different image e.g. Ubuntu 18?

Comment: @heynnema I have the impression that it might be an Ubuntu issue after all.

Comment: @LaraLarsen having a `Wired Connection 1` indicates that you also have a `Wired Connection`. Delete `Wired Connection 1` and check the settings in `Wired Connection`. Reboot. Retry Internet. If that doesn't work, try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if Internet works. Report back.

Comment: @LaraLarsen  Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for updates. Also try booting a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see if ethernet works.